# Socket communication works well until the server suddenly stops receiving data from the client

Tags: android, api, sockets, server, bufferedreader

I'm working on a game which use socket communications to send data between an android client and an API. The API is a Spring application deployed on a local Tomcat. Everything works well until the server suddenly stops receiving data from the client.

I check that the socket is connected and not close, and the logs of the android studio prove that the data was sent.

[image]

The server socket is connected too, so I don't understand what is going on.

This is my server client class:

```
public class Clienthandler implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;

private InputStreamReader objectInputStream;
private OutputStreamWriter objectOutputStream;

private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

private GetObject listener;

private List<AccionOnline> accionesToSent = new ArrayList<>();

private Controler controler = Controler.getInstance();


public Clienthandler(Socket socket, Server server) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    listener = server;
    objectOutputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectInputStream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(objectInputStream);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (socket.isConnected()) {
        try {
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (line != null && !line.isBlank()) {
                if (isJSONValid(line)) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
                    Object object = null;
                    if (jsonObject.get("type").equals("Usuario")) {
                        Usuario a = new Gson().fromJson(line, Usuario.class);
                        object = a;
                    }
                    if (jsonObject.get("type").equals("Accion")) {
                        AccionOnline accionOnline = new Gson().fromJson(line, AccionOnline.class);
                        if (accionOnline.getId() == null) {
                            accionOnline.setId(accionOnline.createID());
                        }
                        object = accionOnline;
                    }
                    listener.receive(object);
                } else {
                    AccionOnline accionOnline = accionesToSent.stream()
                            .filter(accion -> accion.getId().equals(line))
                            .findAny().orElse(null);
                    if (accionOnline != null) {
                        accionOnline.setSent(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

public boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void sendCheck(AccionOnline accionOnline) {
    if (!accionesToSent.contains(accionOnline)) {
        accionesToSent.add(accionOnline);
    }
    Delay.doIt(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (accionOnline.isSent()) {
                accionesToSent.remove(accionOnline);
            } else if (accionOnline.getNumIntentos() < 5) {
                sendCheck(accionOnline);
                accionOnline.setNumIntentos();
            }
        }
    }, 1);
    send(controler.jsonAtor(accionOnline));
}

public void send(String line) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            objectOutputStream.write(line + "\n");
            objectOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

}

And that's my client of the android application:

```
public abstract class Client {

private static SocketContainer mSocketContainer;
public static ReceiveTask receiveTask;

public static class CreateSocketAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SocketContainer> {

    private final String mServerAddress;
    private final int mServerPort;
    private GetObject listener;

    public CreateSocketAsyncTask(String serverAddress, int serverPort, GetObject listener) {
        mServerAddress = serverAddress;
        mServerPort = serverPort;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    protected SocketContainer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(mServerAddress, mServerPort);
            return new SocketContainer(socket, new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Bocholate", "Error: " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SocketContainer socketContainer) {
        super.onPostExecute(socketContainer);
        mSocketContainer = socketContainer;
        receiveTask = new ReceiveTask(listener);
        receiveTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        new WriteSocketAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ConfigProperties.UsuarioSesion);

    }
}


public static class ReceiveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Object, Void> {

    private List<GetObject> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<AccionOnline> accionesRecividas = new ArrayList<>();

    public ReceiveTask(GetObject getObject) {
        super();
        listeners.add(getObject);
    }

    public void add(GetObject object) {
        listeners.add(object);
    }

    private boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
        try {
            new JSONObject(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        while (mSocketContainer.getSocket().isConnected()) {
            try {
                String line = mSocketContainer.bufferedReader.readLine();
                Log.d("Bocholate", "Recibido: " + line);
                if (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    if (isJSONValid(line)) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);
                        Object object;
                        if (jsonObject.get("type").equals("Usuario")) {
                            object = new Gson().fromJson(line, Usuario.class);
                        } else {
                            AccionOnline accionOnline = new Gson().fromJson(line, AccionOnline.class);
                            object = accionOnline;
                            //----------verificacion----------
                            mSocketContainer.getObjectOutputStream().write(accionOnline.getId() + "\n");
                            mSocketContainer.getObjectOutputStream().flush();
                            //--------------------------------
                            if(!accionesRecividas.contains(accionOnline)){
                                accionesRecividas.add(accionOnline);
                            }else{
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        for (GetObject getObject : listeners) {
                            getObject.getObject(object);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Bocholate", "Error: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class WriteSocketAsyncTask<T> extends AsyncTask<T, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(T... ts) {
        try {
            T object = ts[0];
            String jsonInString = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create().toJson(object);
            JSONObject mJSONObject = new JSONObject(jsonInString);
            mJSONObject.put("type", object instanceof Usuario ? "Usuario" : "Accion");
            Log.d("Bocholate", "Enviado: " + mJSONObject);
            Log.d("Bocholate", "conectado: " + mSocketContainer.getSocket().isConnected() +" / "+mSocketContainer.getSocket().isClosed());
            mSocketContainer.getObjectOutputStream().write(mJSONObject + "\n");
            mSocketContainer.getObjectOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Bocholate", "Error: " + e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private static class SocketContainer {

    private Socket mSocket;
    private OutputStreamWriter objectOutputStream;
    private InputStreamReader objectInputStream;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    private SocketContainer(Socket socket, InputStreamReader socketInputStream, OutputStreamWriter socketOutputStream) throws IOException {
        mSocket = socket;
        objectOutputStream = socketOutputStream;
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectInputStream = socketInputStream;
        this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(objectInputStream);
    }

    private Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }

    public OutputStreamWriter getObjectOutputStream() {
        return objectOutputStream;
    }

    public InputStreamReader getObjectInputStream() {
        return objectInputStream;
    }
}
```

}